# Identify the lowest child record when parents are in the same table - leaf nodes?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I have a table which contains parent and child records. The number of generations of children can vary but this is identified by the `[ElementLevelID]` field. All records have an `[ElementID]` but child records have a `[ParentElementID]`. The following code returns all values for three generations of children, though there could be fewer:

```
SELECT     
    tbElement_2.ElementID AS E, 
    tbElement_2.ParentElementID AS PE, 
    tbElement_2.Description AS D, 
    tbElement_2.ElementPath AS P
FROM
    tbElement 
INNER JOIN
    tbElement AS tbElement_2 
INNER JOIN
    tbElement AS tbElement_1 ON tbElement_2.ParentElementID = tbElement_1.ElementID ON tbElement.ElementID = tbElement_1.ParentElementID
WHERE     
    (tbElement.Status = 0) 
    AND (tbElement_1.Status = 0) 
    AND (tbElement_2.Status = 0) 
    AND (tbElement_2.ElementLevelID = 3)

UNION ALL

SELECT     
    tbElement_1.ElementID AS E, 
    tbElement_1.ParentElementID AS PE, 
    tbElement_1.Description AS D, 
    tbElement_1.ElementPath AS P
FROM 
    tbElement 
INNER JOIN
    tbElement AS tbElement_1 ON tbElement.ElementID = tbElement_1.ParentElementID
WHERE     
    (tbElement.Status = 0) 
    AND (tbElement_1.Status = 0) 
    AND (tbElement_1.ElementLevelID = 2)

UNION ALL

SELECT     
    ElementID AS E, 
    tbElement.ParentElementID AS PE, 
    Description AS D, 
    ElementPath AS P
FROM         
    tbElement
WHERE
    (Status = 0) AND (ElementLevelID = 1)

ORDER BY P
```

This returns values:

```
ElementID ParentELementID Desc               ElementLevelID CombinedDesc
    '37841' 'NULL'        'Ceilings'         '1' 'Ceilings'
    '37842' '37841'       'Concrete Soffit'  '2' 'Ceilings/Concrete Soffit'
    '37843' '37842'       'Plaster'          '3' 'Ceilings/Concrete Soffit/Plaster'
```

I want to limit the results to records that have no child records ie just the last record above. I tried adding a sub-query like `AND (tbElement_2.ElementID NOT IN (SELECT tbElement_1.ParentElementID FROM tbElement_1))` but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: by "limit the results to records that have no child" you mean to retrieve only leaf nodes or retrieve all data and stop once reach leaf nodes?

Comment: In this [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) the nodes without children are 2,5,11,4 - nodes without children can be called leafs. So do you want the leaf nodes `2,5,11,4` or the nodes one level above `6,9`?
The node 7 would not be included because it has grandchildren as well.

Comment: Sorry for the delay responding. Yes, it is just the leaf nodes that I want to return, no root or intermediate nodes (ie any record with a child)

Comment: I think I have solved this with the following: 
`SELECT ElementID, ParentElementID, ElementPath FROM tbElement
WHERE ElementID NOT IN 
(SELECT ParentElementID FROM tbElement WHERE ParentElementID IS NOT NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

```
  CREATE TABLE tbElement
(
    ElementID INT,
    ParentElementID INT,
    [Description] VARCHAR(100),
    ElementLevelID INT
)

INSERT INTO tbElement
SELECT '37841', NULL,        'Ceilings',         1 UNION ALL
SELECT '37842', '37841',       'Concrete Soffit',  2  UNION ALL
SELECT '37843', '37842',       'Plaster',         3 UNION ALL
SELECT '37844', NULL,        'Ceilings',         1 UNION ALL
SELECT '37845', 37844,        'Ceilings',         2 UNION ALL
SELECT '37846', NULL,        'Ceilings',         1 




SELECT tb1.*
FROM tbElement tb1
LEFT JOIN tbElement tb2
ON tb1.ElementID = tb2.ParentElementID
WHERE tb2.ParentElementID IS NULL
```

Comment: this retrieves parents .. I think it is not related to the question

Comment: This Query returns required result(only third row).

Comment: I think this assumes that there will always be three levels but this isn't the case, there may be more or less than 3. I have data with as few as 2 and as many as 6 levels of parent/child relationship.

Comment: It will work for more or less than 3 levels also.Edited the answer to add few more scenarios.